# How to apply subdivision modifier to shape key?

Tags: shape-keys, subdivision-surface

For my first animation in blender, I have modelled a person and I animated it. I realise that my person appears whithout her subdivision when I render.
I remember that I have forgotten to apply subdivision modifier but when I try to apply the subdivision modifier it doesn't work, because my character has a shape key.

Comment: you dont need to apply a subdivision modifier unless you want to edit the subdivided vertices. shape keys work fine with the subdivision modifier. Check if you activated the camera button an the subdivision modifier an make sure your render subdivisions are more than or equal your view subdivs

Answer (score 1):

If the subdivision doesn't show up in your render, it may be because the subdivision modifier was disabled for rendering. There are two enable/disable buttons, one for the viewport and one for rendering.

For more details, see the [Modifiers Interface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) section of the Blender manual.